# Copy contents of page to clipboard

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I am looking for the most effective way to copy the contents of a webpage to a clipboard. For example i would like to have a  button on my page so that users can click it and it will copy the contents in text to their clipboard.

is there a cross browser compatible plugin (jquery) or has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: thank you for your answers guys, anything i can do without using flash?

Comment: Sorry but without flash it's simply not possible in most browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we are, I use that: **http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/**

This plugin use **Flash** to make it possible.

Without flash it's simply not possible in most browsers.

Comment: yep. But is very lightweight, cross-browsing.

Comment: Is there any plugin with out Flash? We do avoid Flash player dependency and want more SEO friendly site (less flash)

Comment: There is no SEO conflict with this plugin. It makes just a clone of your formatted text to obj and enable the copy to clipboard.

Comment: thank you for your answers guys, anything i can do without using flash?

Comment: Sorry but without flash it's simply not possible in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

this jquery plugin is cross-compatibleand work fine

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

or

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-copy-clipboard-4-options/#.UGlvF6AURNQ

both are good

Comment: thank you for your answers guys, anything i can do without using flash?

Answer (score 0):

Right now this will require flash since no cross platform api exists so far for clipboard handling (think something like the fullscreen api, where a page would ask for your permission to touch the clipboard - a [draft specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/) exists, but I don't think so it's implemented anywhere).